# How to contain jQuery datepicker within div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

***UPDATES*: I tried the suggestions below but they did not work.**
I want to contain the calendar within the white div with a dark grey border (class = "profileEdit"), and only have its overflow viewable by scrolling. Right now, it's spilling onto profileEdit's parent divs.

***SELECTED HTML***

```
<div class="profileEdit">

            <div class="profilePic">
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameEdit" placeholder="Damon">

            <form class="habitForm">
                <h2>MY EXERCISE HABIT</h2>
                <div class="habitFormGroup">
                    <div class="custom-select">
                        <select>
                            <option value="0">Before</option>
                            <option value="1">After</option>
                            <option value="2">During</option>
                            <option value="3">Every time</option>
                            <option value="4">When</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="triggerEdit" placeholder="breakfast">
                    <p class="punctuation">,</p>
                </div>
                <p class="helperText">trigger</p>
                <div class="habitFormGroup lockedLesson">
                    <p>I will</p>
                    <div class="exerciseEdit"></div>
                    <p class="punctuation">.</p>
                </div>
                <p class="helperText lockedLesson" id="exerciseHelper">exercise</p>
                <div class="habitFormGroup lockedLesson">
                    <div class="exerciseEdit"></div>
                    <p>is my reward.</p>

                </div>
                <p class="helperText lockedLesson">reward</p>
            </form>
            <div class="reminderSwitch">
                <p>Remind me to perform habit</p>
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form class="reminderControls">
                    <label for="startDate">Start:</label>
                    <!-- CALENDAR -->
                    <div class="dateParent">
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <a href='menu.html'><button id="saveButton">Save</button></a>
        </div>
```

***DATEPICKER JQUERY***

```
$(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

***DATEPICKER CSS***

```
.profileEdit {
text-align: center;
padding: 1.5rem;
margin: 3rem 1.5rem;
border: grey solid;
border-radius: 3px;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: relative;
}

#ui-datepicker-div {
position: absolute;
width: 280px;
font-family: frutigerLight;
}

.ui-widget-header.ui-widget-header {
background: none;
background-color: white;
border: none;
}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE: Solution works, but messes up spacing: The space between the "Starts" toggles on and off as well.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: "white div" is not very descriptive. If you want to target anything, right click on the element and select "Inspect" or "Inspect element". Work your way up the DOM until you find the element that encompasses everything you want. You could also just look at [the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming), which says the outer wrapper has a class of `ui-datepicker`.

Comment: CSS and all the divs would be helpful too. You write about a div, but there’s no div in the code that you shared.

Comment: And forcing this date format (with Today) is not practical, it will be changed whenever the user changes the date and the datepicker won’t be able to read it.

Comment: ui-datepicker worked, thanks! I mentioned white div to help you understand the picture. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code, but there is not the bordered div, so I can’t deal with the overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/1weo3yxj/

Comment: @RatajS im aware, but im doing this for prototyping purposes. i'm a ux designer, but coding for a class. Thanks for your help though!

//// Oh, I didn't include the bordered div code in the question. I figured showing me how to contain it within any div would help me since I figured the answer lied in jquery's end.

Comment: You can try to apply `#ui-datepicker-div { position: static !important; }` if you don’t want the element to be floating.

Comment: @RatajS I tried your suggestions, but none worked. I added more code to my question; hope im more clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inline datepicker and control its visibility with JavaScript:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.dateParent').datepicker({ inline: true, altField: '#datepicker' });
  $('#datepicker').focus(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.ui-datepicker').addClass('shown');
    return false;
  });
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is('.dateParent *'))
      $('.ui-datepicker').removeClass('shown');;
  });
});
```

```css
.profileEdit {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  margin: 3rem 1.5rem;
  border: grey solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-datepicker {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.ui-datepicker.shown {
  visibility: visible;
  height: initial;
}

.ui-widget-header.ui-widget-header {
  background: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">


<div class="profileEdit">

  <div class="profilePic">
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameEdit" placeholder="Damon">

  <form class="habitForm">
    <h2>MY EXERCISE HABIT</h2>
    <div class="habitFormGroup">
      <div class="custom-select">
        <select>
          <option value="0">Before</option>
          <option value="1">After</option>
          <option value="2">During</option>
          <option value="3">Every time</option>
          <option value="4">When</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="triggerEdit" placeholder="breakfast">
      <p class="punctuation">,</p>
    </div>
    <p class="helperText">trigger</p>
    <div class="habitFormGroup lockedLesson">
      <p>I will</p>
      <div class="exerciseEdit"></div>
      <p class="punctuation">.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="helperText lockedLesson" id="exerciseHelper">exercise</p>
    <div class="habitFormGroup lockedLesson">
      <div class="exerciseEdit"></div>
      <p>is my reward.</p>

    </div>
    <p class="helperText lockedLesson">reward</p>
  </form>
  <div class="reminderSwitch">
    <p>Remind me to perform habit</p>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form class="reminderControls">
      <label for="startDate">Start:</label>
      <!-- CALENDAR -->
      <div class="dateParent">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <a href='menu.html'><button id="saveButton">Save</button></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution works, but messes up spacing: The space between the "Starts" toggles on and off as well (see pics)

Comment: nevermind, I fixed it! THANK YOU SOO MUCH!!!! :D

Comment: @chickpea You can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove height attr from calendar element. If it doesnt work check this [jQuery UI inline Datepicker auto-resize to parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581462/jquery-ui-inline-datepicker-auto-resize-to-parent-container)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As a UX designer I'd think that you want to either make the containing DIV larger (personally think a popup like the calendar shouldn't extend outside it's container) or possibly change the direction that the calendar control opens in relative to the mouse position. If your trigger control is at the bottom of it's container you have the calendar pop upwards instead of down.